# Tags disappeared from tagcloud in highcharts while using deriveFontSize method

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I will be working on highcharts wordcloud. Sometimes it behaves unexpectedly. So i will be giving fontsize for each tags using `deriveFontSize` method. Here the code goes.

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.wordcloud.prototype.deriveFontSize = function(relativeWeight) {
  var maxFontSize = 55;
  // Will return a fontSize based on maxFontSize.
  var rWeight = Math.floor(maxFontSize * relativeWeight);
  var size = rWeight < 1 ? 1 : rWeight;
  return size;
};
```

so the `maxFontSize` i given is `55`. When i am executing the code again and again in the fiddle some of the tags are disappearing. The code is working correctly when the `Highcharts.seriesTypes.wordcloud.prototype.deriveFontSize` method is not included. So please help me to solve. Fiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/b5yymr85/1/)

Comment: _The code is working correctly when the Highcharts.seriesTypes.wordcloud.prototype.deriveFontSize method is not included._ It will also work when `maxFontSize` is less ( max 20). It is exceeding the chart area when using higher font size. So why to use high font size

Comment: @Patata For minimum number of tags we are expecting the size of the tag to be bigger.

Comment: So to achieve that you can reduce the data length (minimum number of tags) before creating chart

Comment: I need to show all the tags given as input.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `outsidePlayingField` doesn't work perfectly - I commented it out in `intersectionTesting` function and the plot looks fine (all points are visible):

```
while (
  (
    intersectsAnyWord(point, placed) //||
    //outsidePlayingField(element, field)
  ) && delta !== false
) {
  (...)
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/qmtwspyn/

**API reference about changing core functions:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts